# Translating "The joy of understanding is the highest/greatest pleasure"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

I'm self-taught Latin student and I wanted to translate the following sentence:

> The joy of understanding is the highest/greatest pleasure.

I used the word "highest" there because I wanted to mean that it's noble, as compared for instance with those pleasures which require only sentience.

I did as the following: both

> Voluptas nobilissima gaudium intellegendi est

and

> Intellegendi gaudium voluptas nobilissima est.

Which one is more appropriate? Could it be improved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of your suggestions work.
I would only vary it little for a more Latin style:

- I would say "highest of pleasures" instead of "highest pleasure": *voluptatum nobilissima*.
- In a pithy motto *est* is often best left out.
- I would order it as in English so that you first introduce the joy and only then praise it. (It's also a good idea to play with slightly different word orders to see what sounds best to your ear.)
- I would prefer to replace *nobilis* ("well known", related to *novisse*, not really "high") with *altus*. It means things like "high", "deep", "profound", and "great". Or even better than *altissimus*, go with *summus*. (I had overlooked this word until I noticed the comment by C. M. Weimer.)

With these ideas I'd polish your suggestions to:

> *Gaudium intellegendi voluptatum altissima/summa.*

Or if you think that *gaudium* and *voluptas* are too close, you could say:

> *Voluptatum altissima/summa illa intellegendi.*
> The noblest of pleasures is that of understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was really helpful! I'd rather use "Gaudium intellegendi voluptatum altissima." then, sounds better to my ear and seems more Latin when I read it.

Answer (score 5):

I think Batavulus and Joonas are close, but I think the answers so far are hindered in attempting a literal translation. In your English sentence, *joy* and *pleasure* are essentially synonymous. You are in essence defining *joy* as *pleasure*, but which makes it redundant. Unless you want to specify what *kind* of pleasure, you're actually merely saying, "The joy you get from understanding is the greatest joy," or, "The joy you get from understanding is the best," or even "Understanding makes for the greatest joy." You can substitute pleasure in there with no loss, though the difference between *joy* and *pleasure* is enough for you to specify which.

Alternatively, you can use both in this way: "Understanding leads to the greatest joy and pleasure."

Technically, you could mean something like, "That feeling you get from understanding something (joy) leads to pure pleasure," but it's a nonsensical term. Are you aroused by happiness? Skip one and go for the other.

With that, I would give you the pithy: ***Intellegere est summum gaudium.*** / *To understand is the greatest joy.*

If you wanted to emphasize the pleasure aspect, you'd instead go with: ***Intellegere est summa voluptas.*** / *To understand is the greatest pleasure.*

For comparanda, cf. *errare est humanum* (*To err is human*) and the frequent use of *summum bonum* in authors like Cicero or Seneca (with a citation as early as Terence).

The former is the feeling of elation you get from understanding; the latter is the sensation of pleasure, which will be more sensual than the former.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Then a translation such as "Gaudium altissimum illud intellegendi." would be more appropriate? Because I understand "altissimus" gives me the idea of some "elevate" joy, so to speak, it brings the translation closer to what I intended to say.

Comment: @M.Gonzalez Word order aside, your translation looks like "the joy of understanding something is the highest." Just feels a bit weird with the *illud*. While *altissimum* isn't a bad choice, you can think of *summus* as "highest" like in loftiest, given that we derive the word summit from it. However high *altissimus* is, *summus* is higher still.

Comment: You've been very helpful, thanks! So I could stick with something like "Intellegere summum gaudium", following the advice of @Joonas to left out the "est" in a pithy motto? Or is it better to try first to rephrase my sentence? I intended to say that, among all pleasures, the joy of understanding something is the most elevated. I think even in English the sentence got a bit bizarre...

Comment: @M.Gonzalez You generally don't need *est*, but you absolutely do here, since without it it would mean "to understand the highest joy."

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen your own suggestions, I thought maybe *Intellegendo delectari summum gaudium* or perhaps *Summum gaudium intellegendo delectari* vel sim. For some reason, I don't like *voluptas* in this context, but a bit hard to specify why. Of your suggestions, I like the second best, although to me *nobilis* is not ideal here.

Comment: *summus* should absolutely be used here. Cf. *summum bonum*.

Comment: Gratias ago. Do you have a suggestion yourself? (Out of curiosity, it wasn't my question, after all...)

Comment: Yeah, I'll post my thoughts a little later. I think you're close, but the insistence on the exact words used (which is awkward even in English) makes for awkward Latin.

Comment: You are right, that is a problem. I'll be interested to see what you have.

Comment: And I've submitted.